# NSMutableURLRequest iphone

Tags: objective-c, nsmutableurlrequest

my problem seems to be quite basic, but I can't find it!

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://miip.com"]];
```

and I get this error:

```
 Expected expression
```

I can't find it!

Thanks!

Comment: in my system it printed like this then --> 2012-09-20 16:02:13.610 DemoOfAllCategory[2760:207] THE request::<NSMutableURLRequest http://miip.com>  then what is the issue ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you, did you try it and it worked?

Comment: I found it, is because of it inside a switch-case and I missed {}

Comment: nice keep asking questions...

Comment: you shouldn't be so rude, everybody has stupid troubles. Maybe you could if you had been able to solve it, but you hadn't.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16917/discussion-between-spynet-and-user1256477)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line above is valid.
This sounds like a coding error outside this line.
maybe you are missing a ; in the line before or something like that.